# I can't dislay a Column Chart (Google Chart - Server Side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I try to use Google Charts in one of my projects. My SQL is working good, but I can't get the chart, maybe i need to mention that my data is a number (0.00). I am using my POSTGRESQL DB (server side)

Here's my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['niveau','me1','me2','me3','me4','me5','me6'],

    <?php
        $result = $pdo->query ("SELECT  
                niveau.nom_niveau AS niveau,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e1 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e1 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e1 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me1,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e2 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e2 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e2 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me2,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e3 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e3 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e3 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me3,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e4 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e4 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e4 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me4,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e5 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e5 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e5 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me5,
                ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e6 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e6 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e6 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me6
        FROM mesure , puits, niveau , gisement
        where mesure.cm = puits.cm
        and mesure.num_niveau = niveau.id_niveau
        and gisement.id_gisement = puits.num_gisement
        group by niveau.nom_niveau");

        foreach($result AS $row) {
            echo "['".$row['niveau']."',".$row['me1'].",".$row['me2'].",".$row['me3'].",".$row['me4'].",".$row['me5'].",".$row['me6']."], "; 
        }
    ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: 'Moyenne Pondérée des éléments chimiques en chaque niveau phoshaté' }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));       
  }
  </script>
```

Here's my data table:

[image: Here's my data]

I hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: are there any errors in the browser's console? (press F12 on most)

Comment: yes, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, you are using a single quote / apostrophe to indicate the first column value is a string...

```
echo "['".$row['niveau']."'," ...
```

however, if you look at row 3 in the data table, the value ends with a apostrophe...

```
Couche 0'
```

this is causing the error.

to resolve, you will either need to remove the apostrophe from the data table value...

```
Couche 0
```

or reverse the use of single and double quotes in the echo statement.

```
foreach($result AS $row) {
    echo '["'.$row["niveau"].'",'.$row["me1"].','.$row["me2"].','.$row["me3"].','.$row["me4"].','.$row["me5"].','.$row["me6"].'], '; 
}
```

assuming there are no data table values that include a double quotes.

---

this is why it is not recommended to build the json string manually.
instead, build the data as an array, then encode it on the html page.

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    <?php

      $result = $pdo->query ("SELECT
        niveau.nom_niveau AS niveau,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e1 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e1 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e1 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me1,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e2 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e2 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e2 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me2,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e3 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e3 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e3 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me3,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e4 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e4 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e4 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me4,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e5 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e5 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e5 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me5,
        ROUND (( SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e6 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp*mesure.e6 ELSE null END) / SUM(CASE WHEN mesure.e6 IS NOT NULL THEN mesure.pp ELSE null END)) ,2) AS me6
      FROM mesure , puits, niveau , gisement
      where mesure.cm = puits.cm
      and mesure.num_niveau = niveau.id_niveau
      and gisement.id_gisement = puits.num_gisement
      group by niveau.nom_niveau");

      // create data array
      $data = [];
      $data[] = ['niveau','me1','me2','me3','me4','me5','me6'];
      foreach($result AS $row) {
        $data[] = [$row['niveau'], $row['me1'], $row['me2'], $row['me3'], $row['me4'], $row['me5'], $row['me6']];
      }

      // write data array to page
      echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
  );

  var options = {
      chart: {
      title: '',
      subtitle: 'Moyenne Pondérée des éléments chimiques en chaque niveau phoshaté' }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

furthermore, I would recommend not combining php with html / javascript.
separate the php and html into separate files. then use ajax to get the data from php.
see this answer for an example...

[How to automatically update Google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059614/how-to-automatically-update-google-gauge/62063641#62063641)

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for the help and the advice to.